# Pine Script Multiple Condition / if statement or for-loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have multiple conditions like;

Buy1
Buy2
Buy3
Buy4
Buy5
.
.
.
Buy10

I want to change bar colors due to TRUE condition numbers
*Example: only buy1 true*
If 1 Condition True barcolor(color.red)
*Example: only buy1, buy3, buy5 true*
If 3 Condition True barcolor(color.blue)
If 9 Condition True barcolor(color.green)
.
.

how can i code, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both `plot()` and `alertcondition()` in local scope. What you can do is, write your condition in `series/condition` argument of `plot/alertcondition`.

Below `plot()` call will plot the `close` value wheneever `buy1 and buy2` is true.

```
plot(buy1 and buy2 ? close : na)
alertcondition(buy1 and buy2, "Title", "Message")
```

## **Edit:**

You can pretty much use the ternary operator for every parameter of a function.

To change the color of a bar, use the ternary operator to set its `color` argument.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

cond = high > high[1]
barcolor(cond ? color.yellow : na)
```

[image]

Comment: I determined again my question, i want to change bar colors due to true condition number.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: That s Ok, But I have 10 condition and it changes how many of is TRUE.
Example, 3 of 10 is True for my conditions i want to change the bar color to red, 
5 of the 10 is true i want to change to bar color to blue. These are example, I try to tell logic of my idea.
Your offer is OK but I must write the 10 conditions lots of times with different possibilities

Comment: Conditions may be
RSIOK = RSI14 > RSI EMA 10
MACD = MACD > SIGNAL
EMA = ema4>sma7
etc
I have like this 10 condition and i need to number of how many condition is OK. I ll change the color of bar in accordance with value of the TRUE condition number